# Mersenne primes and lowest divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p_1,p_2,..p_k$ be distinct Mersenne primes let $N = 2^{p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot..p_k}-1$. Let LD(n) be the lowest divisor of n greater than 1.

My question is: Is $LD(N)$ always a Mersenne prime?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something here, it seems that we always have $7|N$, since $(2^3-1)$ is always going to be a factor of $N$. (Are we assuming that $p_1$ is the first Mersenne prime, etc.?)

Comment: @OldJohn I think it's for any collection of Mersenne primes. I'm not sure whether the $p_i$ are assumed distinct, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, they should be distinct.

Comment: @OldJohn: no $p_1$ does not have to be the first Mersenne prime.

Comment: I doubt it. If you pick a Mersenne prime $M_p$ such that $2^{M_p}-1$ is not prime ($M_{13}$ for example), I would be surprised if its smallest prime factor would necessarily be a Mersenne prime. If you compose with large Mersenne primes, there's a chance that the smallest prime factor of the rogue $M_p$ is the smallest overall.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't it known that no Mersenne prime can be a factor of another Mersenne number with prime exponent?  I believe I remember seeing this somewhere, though I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @DanielFischer: In that case we might ask: What is LD(2^2181-1)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why $2181 = 3\cdot 727$? $727$ is not a Mersenne prime. My idea would have you look at $2^{8191}-1$, which looks an even more daunting task.

Comment: Sorry, that's the one I meant.

Comment: @universalset Right, you have $\gcd (a^n-1, a^m-1) = a^{\gcd (n,m)}-1$ for $a > 1$, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that no, in general LD(N) does not need to be a Mersenne prime. $2^{8191}-1$ is not divisible by any Mersenne primes smaller than itself (I checked).

If 3 is among the $p_is$, then as OldJohn points out 7 is a factor.

Comment: Yes, I had worked out about $2^{8191}-1$ not being divisible by any smaller Mersenne prime, but - I did not post it, because I could not prove that the same would be true if we have more than one of the $p_i$s. The numbers become far too big to try hunting for factors, and I have not got a good argument yet for $2^{p_1p_2}-1$ where $p_1$ is 8191 and $p_2$ is bigger. Excellent question, though!

Comment: @OldJohn: I almost feel tempted to ask if there is any prime that doesn't produce remainder 1 if you divide: 2^(8191*131071)-1 by the prime in question. The fact that the remainder 1 occurs so often is rather curious.